# Least-distance scheduling scenario

Tags: sql, db2, traveling-salesman

The other day I had a problem that was kind of interesting. It concerns scheduling a series of "tournaments". The following are the constraints:

- There are 7 teams named A, B, ..., G
- A tournament contains 3 teams, all teams in a tournament plays 1 game against the other 2 teams. I.e. a tournament consists of 3 games
- Each team hosts two tournaments
- Each team travels to four tournaments beside the tournaments they host
- When the series is done all teams should have played all other teams twice

Each travel is associated with a distance. The goal is to find a schedule such that the difference between the shortest and the longest travelling team is minimal.

Not exactly a traveling-salesman problem, but sort of related. I'll be happy to remove that tag if there are strong opinions against it.

Some sample data:

```
create table d
(   source      varchar(20) not null
,   destination      varchar(20) not null
,   distance    int not null
,       primary key (source, destination) );

insert into d (source, destination, distance)
select 'A', destination, distance
from (values  ('B',204)
          ,   ('C',31)
          ,   ('D',185)
          ,   ('E',213)
          ,   ('F',142)
          ,   ('G',165)
     ) T(destination, distance);

insert into d (source, destination, distance)
select 'B', destination, distance
from (values ('C',230)
        ,    ('D',102)
        ,    ('E',169)
        ,    ('F',152)
        ,    ('G',224)
     ) T(destination, distance);

insert into d (source, destination, distance)
select 'C', destination, distance
from (values ('D',200)
            ,('E',224)
            ,('F',157)
            ,('G',135)
     ) T(destination, distance);

insert into d (source, destination, distance)
select 'D', destination, distance
from (values ('E',68)
            ,('F',51)
            ,('G',123)
     ) T(destination, distance);

insert into d (source, destination, distance)
select 'E', destination, distance
from (values ('F',52)
        ,    ('G',88)
     ) T(destination, distance);

insert into d (source, destination, distance)
select 'F', destination, distance
from (values   ('G',80)
     ) T(destination, distance);

create view dv as
select source, destination, distance from d
union all
select destination, source, distance from d;
```

I started out with the assumption that it would be easiest to pick 4 travels for each team and filter from there. Let's call this relation team_travel. By cross-joining A's team_travels with B's team_travel etc we get all possible combinations of team_travels. From there we can exclude those that does not contain exactly 4 'A', 4 'B', etc. By ordering what remains with the difference of the greatest and the least travel distance we can get the result.

This is butt-ugly and can certainly be improved:

```
create or replace function cnt_occ(s varchar(28), c varchar(1))
returns int
    return values length(s) - length(replace(s,c,null));

with t(s,d,n) as (
    select source, destination, distance
    from dv
), team_travel(s, d1,d2,d3,d4,n1,n2,n3,n4) as (
    select t1.s, t1.d, t2.d, t3.d, t4.d, t1.n,t2.n,t3.n,t4.n
    from t as t1
    join t as t2
        on t2.d > t1.d
        and t1.s = t2.s
    join t as t3
        on t3.d > t2.d
        and t1.s = t3.s
    join t as t4
        on t4.d > t3.d
        and t1.s = t4.s
    where t1.s not in (t1.d,t2.d,t3.d,t4.d)
)
select
       a1.s||'->'||a1.d1||a1.d2||a1.d3||a1.d4,a1.n1+a1.n2+a1.n3+a1.n4
    ,  a2.s||'->'||a2.d1||a2.d2||a2.d3||a2.d4,a2.n1+a2.n2+a2.n3+a2.n4
    ,  a3.s||'->'||a3.d1||a3.d2||a3.d3||a3.d4,a3.n1+a3.n2+a3.n3+a3.n4
    ,  a4.s||'->'||a4.d1||a4.d2||a4.d3||a4.d4,a4.n1+a4.n2+a4.n3+a4.n4
    ,  a5.s||'->'||a5.d1||a5.d2||a5.d3||a5.d4,a5.n1+a5.n2+a5.n3+a5.n4
    ,  a6.s||'->'||a6.d1||a6.d2||a6.d3||a6.d4,a6.n1+a6.n2+a6.n3+a6.n4
    ,  a7.s||'->'||a7.d1||a7.d2||a7.d3||a7.d4,a7.n1+a7.n2+a7.n3+a7.n4
    ,  greatest(a1.n1+a1.n2+a1.n3+a1.n4
            ,  a2.n1+a2.n2+a2.n3+a2.n4
            ,  a3.n1+a3.n2+a3.n3+a3.n4
            ,  a4.n1+a4.n2+a4.n3+a4.n4
            ,  a5.n1+a5.n2+a5.n3+a5.n4
            ,  a6.n1+a6.n2+a6.n3+a6.n4
            ,  a7.n1+a7.n2+a7.n3+a7.n4)
    -  least(a1.n1+a1.n2+a1.n3+a1.n4
        ,  a2.n1+a2.n2+a2.n3+a2.n4
        ,  a3.n1+a3.n2+a3.n3+a3.n4
        ,  a4.n1+a4.n2+a4.n3+a4.n4
        ,  a5.n1+a5.n2+a5.n3+a5.n4
        ,  a6.n1+a6.n2+a6.n3+a6.n4
        ,  a7.n1+a7.n2+a7.n3+a7.n4) as min_diff
from       ( select * from team_travel where s = 'A' ) as a1
cross join ( select * from team_travel where s = 'B' ) as a2
cross join ( select * from team_travel where s = 'C' ) as a3
cross join ( select * from team_travel where s = 'D' ) as a4
cross join ( select * from team_travel where s = 'E' ) as a5
cross join ( select * from team_travel where s = 'F' ) as a6
cross join ( select * from team_travel where s = 'G' ) as a7
where cnt_occ(a1.d1||a1.d2||a1.d3||a1.d4
            ||a2.d1||a2.d2||a2.d3||a2.d4
            ||a3.d1||a3.d2||a3.d3||a3.d4
            ||a4.d1||a4.d2||a4.d3||a4.d4
            ||a5.d1||a5.d2||a5.d3||a5.d4
            ||a6.d1||a6.d2||a6.d3||a6.d4
            ||a7.d1||a7.d2||a7.d3||a7.d4, 'A') = 4
  and cnt_occ(a1.d1||a1.d2||a1.d3||a1.d4
            ||a2.d1||a2.d2||a2.d3||a2.d4
            ||a3.d1||a3.d2||a3.d3||a3.d4
            ||a4.d1||a4.d2||a4.d3||a4.d4
            ||a5.d1||a5.d2||a5.d3||a5.d4
            ||a6.d1||a6.d2||a6.d3||a6.d4
            ||a7.d1||a7.d2||a7.d3||a7.d4, 'B') = 4
  and cnt_occ(a1.d1||a1.d2||a1.d3||a1.d4
            ||a2.d1||a2.d2||a2.d3||a2.d4
            ||a3.d1||a3.d2||a3.d3||a3.d4
            ||a4.d1||a4.d2||a4.d3||a4.d4
            ||a5.d1||a5.d2||a5.d3||a5.d4
            ||a6.d1||a6.d2||a6.d3||a6.d4
            ||a7.d1||a7.d2||a7.d3||a7.d4, 'C') = 4
  and cnt_occ(a1.d1||a1.d2||a1.d3||a1.d4
            ||a2.d1||a2.d2||a2.d3||a2.d4
            ||a3.d1||a3.d2||a3.d3||a3.d4
            ||a4.d1||a4.d2||a4.d3||a4.d4
            ||a5.d1||a5.d2||a5.d3||a5.d4
            ||a6.d1||a6.d2||a6.d3||a6.d4
            ||a7.d1||a7.d2||a7.d3||a7.d4, 'D') = 4
  and cnt_occ(a1.d1||a1.d2||a1.d3||a1.d4
            ||a2.d1||a2.d2||a2.d3||a2.d4
            ||a3.d1||a3.d2||a3.d3||a3.d4
            ||a4.d1||a4.d2||a4.d3||a4.d4
            ||a5.d1||a5.d2||a5.d3||a5.d4
            ||a6.d1||a6.d2||a6.d3||a6.d4
            ||a7.d1||a7.d2||a7.d3||a7.d4, 'E') = 4
  and cnt_occ(a1.d1||a1.d2||a1.d3||a1.d4
            ||a2.d1||a2.d2||a2.d3||a2.d4
            ||a3.d1||a3.d2||a3.d3||a3.d4
            ||a4.d1||a4.d2||a4.d3||a4.d4
            ||a5.d1||a5.d2||a5.d3||a5.d4
            ||a6.d1||a6.d2||a6.d3||a6.d4
            ||a7.d1||a7.d2||a7.d3||a7.d4, 'F') = 4
  and cnt_occ(a1.d1||a1.d2||a1.d3||a1.d4
            ||a2.d1||a2.d2||a2.d3||a2.d4
            ||a3.d1||a3.d2||a3.d3||a3.d4
            ||a4.d1||a4.d2||a4.d3||a4.d4
            ||a5.d1||a5.d2||a5.d3||a5.d4
            ||a6.d1||a6.d2||a6.d3||a6.d4
            ||a7.d1||a7.d2||a7.d3||a7.d4, 'G') = 4
order by min_diff
fetch first 100 rows only
```

There has to be something more elegant than this, thoughts?

Comment: Are you open to a solution that goes beyond SQL, like Oracle's PL/SQL? In management science normally we approach these from deterministic dynamic programming. -- that may give you a route to an answer.

Comment: Well, I just thought it would be interesting with a declarative solution to the problem. I assume you by "deterministic dynamic programming" mean for example the simplex method, and yes that would probably be much more efficient. But in that case I would probably skip SQL completely.

Comment: I think the most elegant solutions will sadly, lie outside of sql.